# How to set Environment Variable and How to pass the environment Variable as a parameter

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

In package.json file I have some list of task under the scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test:smoketest":"cucumber-js --format json:./reports/cucumber-json-report.json --tags '@Smoke_Test'",
    "test:regressiontest":"cucumber-js --format json:./reports/cucumber-json-report.json --tags '@Regression_Test'",
    "test:UI":"cucumber-js --format json:./reports/cucumber-json-report.json --tags '@UI'"
  },
```

I will be executing the script with the command Eg: npm run test:smoketest(npm run test:testname)I want to pass this test name in a function to check for a if condition like

test.js

```
async function(){
if(testname=="UI"){
some tasks need to be done
}
else{
some task need to be done
}
```

can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It kind of depends. What OS?

Comment: Its Ubuntu..... @slebetman

Answer (score 0):

Steps For creating runtime-environment variable
In Terminal

1. Firstly we need to install the command **npm install dotenv --save-dev** . This command will install dotenv module in your node modules folder.
2. For setting up environment variable in runtime (during execution), we need to execute the command

   **`type=<type name> npm run test:<test name>`**

> Eg: type=Uitest npm run test:UI

This command will create a run time variable type with value Uitest while executing the UI test

**Passing this environment variable as a parameter in test.js file**

```
async function(){
if(process.env.type=="Uitest"){
some tasks need to be done
}
else if(process.env.type!="Uitest"){
some task need to be done
}
else{
some task need to be done
}
```

-----While executing the code when the environment variable is with type Uitest then the set of code under if will get executed. When the environment variable is not with type Uitest then the set of code under else if will get executed.When no environment variable is set during run time

> **eg:npm run test:UI**

then the set of code in else will get executed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide arbitrary data to your support code at runtime, the supported way is to pass in [world parameters](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#world-parameters) via the CLI.

This is much easier done using [profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#profiles) (which would also probably simplify your package.json scripts, or at least move the complexity into your cucumber.js config).